# Using values inside a function out side

Tags: php, function

is it possible to use values that are obtained within a loop/function out side the loop/function where it is used or called?

below is my function

```
function off($limit)
{
    $string=file_get_contents("feed.xml");
    $xml=simplexml_load_string($string);

    foreach ($xml->FOUND->CAT as $place)
    {
        $limits = $place->CORDS;
        $rate=$place->STARS;
        $phone=$place->PHONE;
    }
}
```

Im calling it to a php file which has html tags. Is it possible to get the values that are returned by the function into the rows that are marked by XXXX to display ?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
off(‘57854’);
?>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
    <td>XXXXX</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know is there a way to display without including the html tags within the function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you cannot do looping without PHP, so your HTML has to be inside a loop. But you can return a simplified array from your function, if that helps:

```
function off($limit)
{
    $string = file_get_contents("feed.xml");
    $xml    = simplexml_load_string($string); 
    $return = array();

    foreach ($xml->FOUND->CAT as $place)
    {
        $return[] = array(
            'limits' => $place->CORDS,
            'rate' => $place->STARS,
            'phone' => $place->PHONE
        )
    }
    return $return;        
}
```

The function now builds an array of the results to be returned back to the caller. Then you can just loop through that array:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$arr = off('57854');
?>
<table width="200" border="1">
    <?php foreach($arr as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['limits']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This way, you can avoid having HTML inside your function, which is always a good thing to do – keep your logic separate from the presentation.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is exactly what the OP asked for, with an clear example.

Answer (score 2):

you put a [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement in your function. then you can use it "outside"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the result of a function and use it outside.  Example:

```
function addSomething($a, $b)
{
    $sum = $a + $b;
    return $sum;
}

$mySum = addSomething(15, 45);

print $mySum;  // Will show 60
```

You can only 'return' one variable as it will 'exit' the function once you return.  If you need more data than just a single variable you can return an array and pick that up on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value out of the function:

```
function foo() {
  return array("bar");
}
```

Any time I call `foo()`, I'll be able to catch it's return value:

```
$items = foo(); // $items is now array("bar");

foreach($items as $item) {
  print "<td>" . $item . "</td>"; // <td>bar</td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways:

1., Either you save result of each loop turnaround into an array and then loop through array

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($array as $a){
echo "<tr><td>$a</td></tr>";
} ?>
</table>
```

2., or you echo each row through the loop (in that `off` function)

3., or you start a buffer with `ob_start` and then save it to some variable (`$result = ob_get_contents()`)

Either way, you'll need more loops and some `echo`s.

Answer (score -1):

Not without making each of the function variables global

```
function func() {
  global $var1, $var2, ...;
  ...
}
?>
<td><?=$var1?></td>
```

Note: for the above to work, short tags must be enabled, otherwise you have to do `<?php echo $var1 ?>`